# How to add rows in mysql table from sql file

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I need to clean a database table. I exported the original table in several sql files, each files containing a group a rows.

I now would like to "push"/insert all files one by one into the new table and assign to each row a new ID (using the auto-increment)

Thank you for your help

Comment: *I exported the original table in several sql files* I think that old `ID` values are saved too - so data restoring will restore their values too.

Comment: Does your structure contains foreign key referrences?

Comment: yes it does have references to other table

Comment: Do you want to add new ID for each group or each row in a group?

Comment: If so then you must restore the database as-is, including old `ID` values, into temporary database, then copy tables data table-by-table into new database with the queries which saves the relation integrity, then remove temporary database.

Comment: I inserted my first file. but When I try to insert the second one, I have got the error saying table already exists

Comment: An example of data copying while preserve the relations can be found [there](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75bba5273669d9d641bf095afd588b57).